# scrollViewDidScroll getting called for uiscrollview inside tablecell while scrolling tableview up and down

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a custom uiscrollview inside each table cell. It works great except one condition. When you scroll the scrollview and it do autoscroll/decelerate. At same time if you scroll table view quickly up and down it also moves the scrollview in the table cell which will result in scrollViewDidScroll getting called for scrollview and messed up with my logic.

Comment: I believe there will no direct answer for it, either there should be some "jugaad" or some change should be made in app working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check which `UIScrollView` is actually scrolling:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == yourScrollView)
    {
        // Do something
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something amazing
    }
}
```